# How to pass command line argument from oc start-build to dockerfile to set environment variable inside dockerfile

Tags: python, docker, command-line, dockerfile, openshift

Used the below commands but the value for environment is not getting passed in Dockerfile.
Running these instances in oc container through groovy script:

`oc start-build -e environment=ipte2 ipte2-isell-api-7 --from-dir=./isell-python-wrapper --follow=true`

```
**WARNING**: Specifying environment variables with binary builds is not supported.
Uploading directory "isell-python-wrapper" as binary input for the build ...
build "ipte2-isell-api-7-1" started
2)oc start-build --build-arg environment=ipte2 ipte2-isell-api-5 --from-dir=./isell-python-wrapper --follow=true

**WARNING**: Specifying build arguments with binary builds is not supported.
Uploading directory "isell-python-wrapper" as binary input for the build ...
build "ipte2-isell-api-5-1" started

error
Removing intermediate container f7ff031b18b1
Step 35/44 : COPY script/${environment}-local.conf /sum/lpp/ebb/local.conf
error: build error: lstat script/-local.conf: no such file or directory
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM wlp-base:0.1 #from statement base image
ARG environment

ENV environment=${environment}

COPY script/${environment}-local.conf
```

I need to pass above environment value inside the copy command 
if i pass `ENV environment=ipte2`
directly inside Dockerfile its working fine. But sending a command line argument, it doesn't get it.

Answer (score 2):

You may try automate editing of the YAML manifest file with the `BuildConfig` (e.g. with the `yaml` python package) to add entries to the `buildArgs` array, which is located in the `dockerStrategy` definition of the `BuildConfig`. For example:

```
dockerStrategy:
...
  buildArgs:
    - name: "foo"
      value: "bar"
```

Refer to the [relevant Openshift docs](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/dev_guide/builds/build_strategies.html#docker-strategy-build-args) for more details.

Comment: Awesome
Thanks for the update Narendra!!!
Its working fro me now

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that in OCP/OKD 3.11 you can't pass env vars via the `--env key=value` argument to `oc start-build` (you get `"WARNING: Specifying environment variables with binary builds is not supported."`), which leaves you with two choices:

- automate editing of the `Dockerfile` (instead of using env vars there),
- automate editing of the YAML manifest file with the `BuildConfig` (e.g. with the `yaml` python package).

Caution: the latter option in my tests turned out to be completely ineffective - env vars were not passed to docker so that `Dockerfile` could not be parametrized with them.

Answer (score 0):

This works when using simple `docker build --build-arg environment=foo .`

I haven't used `oc` before, but if you find a way of specifiying the build arg like in
https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.6/dev_guide/builds/build_strategies.html#docker-strategy-build-args

Comment: details passed in the dockerfile is it right?
FROM wlp-base:0.1 #from statement base image
ARG environment

ENV environment=${environment}

COPY script/${environment}-local.conf